# multiple custom markers (icons) with different infowindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, markers

I'm creating a map where I will be adding multiple custom markers, and I want each of them to have different infowindows. 
The thing is that every marker has a different icon (those numbered dots you see in the image), and this is an example that is not explained on the GoogleMaps API code samples. I mean, they explain you how to create infowindows, but only in the case you are using the variable `marker`, and not for the variable `icons`. Therefore, I don't know where should I add the code for the infowindow. The website looks like this:

[website screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtYGn.jpg)

```
 <script>
  var map;
  function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.404998, 2.210517),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
      streetViewControl: false,

    });

    var iconBase = 'images/numbers/';
    var icons = {
      001: {
        icon: iconBase + '01.png'
      },
      002: {
        icon: iconBase + '02.png'
      }
    };

    function addMarker(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
        map: map
      });
    }

    var features = [
      {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.404998, 2.210517),
        type: 001
        //Barcelona 1
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.404371, 2.179131),
        type: 002
        //Barcelona 2
      }
    ];

 for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
  addMarker(feature);
};    
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering Josep last question if I may (I'm new in Stack Overflow so please forgive my imprecisions), I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t7trcpv2/1/, adding to the 'feature' object a 'title' property where you can input your own data

```
var map;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.404998, 2.210517),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    streetViewControl: false,
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var iconBase = 'images/numbers/';
  var icons = {
    001: {
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
    },
    002: {
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png"
    }
  };

  function addMarker(feature) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: feature.position,
      icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
      map: map,

    });
    // must be a string (or a DOM node).
    var content = "" + feature.title
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
      return function(evt) {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, content, infowindow));

  }

  var features = [{
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.404998, 2.210517),
    type: 001,
    title:'title1'
      //Barcelona 1
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.404371, 2.179131),
    type: 002,
    title: 'title2'
      //Barcelona 2
  }];

  for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
    addMarker(feature);
  };
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

Comment: You suggestion is correct but you should add a proper  sample code (not necessarily completely original).. the link answer  by the time the  may become ineffective while the sample code remains

Answer (score 1):

try using closure this way

```
  var features = [
    {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.404998, 2.210517),
      type: 001
      //Barcelona 1
    }, {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.404371, 2.179131),
      type: 002
      //Barcelona 2
    }
  ];




   function addMarker(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
        map: map
      });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

    var content  = "" + feature.type

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
      };
    })(marker,content,infowindow)); 

  }
```

you could change features this way

```
var features = [
  {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.404998, 2.210517),
    type: 001,
    message:  'my firts message in info window'
    //Barcelona 1
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.404371, 2.179131),
    type:  002,
    message:  'my second message in info window'
    //Barcelona 2
  }
];
```

or you can add a new property

you should use

```
 function addMarker(feature) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    map: map
  });

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

var content  = "" + feature.message

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  };
})(marker,content,infowindow));
```

Comment: content needs to be a string (or a DOM node) (a number results in a blank infowindow and an error message `InvalidValueError: setContent: not a string;`).  [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/t7trcpv2/)

Comment: @geocodezip   .correct (as usual)  thanks  .. answer  updated .. I had not noticed that it was just a number

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks a lot! Now infowindows do show up. But they display numbers: '1' for icon 001 and '2' for icon 002. I want them to display different information, but can't figure out where do I have to place the content string (I supose I have to do that..?)

Comment: @JosepFonti    . if you look at the sample in answer  you see that the info assigned for infowindow at the var content come form feature.type .. so if you need  other info change this value in your array or add and manage a new property in fetaure

Comment: @JosepFonti   this is because infowindow need  text  but  feature.type is auto cast to number for avoid this the sintax ""+ feature.type   force javascript to cast the result as a string so in accepted  by inforwindow content ... hope is clear ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Ok! I replaced feature.type for feature.title (and added a title feature under var features, where I insert the text I would like to show up inside the infowindow). But doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks for your help, but doesn't work: I can't change the type names, because they are related with the icons (type 001 is for the icon showing the number 1. And then, feature.message is not recognized by the console... Any idea or alternative that could work..

Comment: if you can't change nothings  .. how i can suggest you somethings .?. what i suggested .is basic  ..

Comment: sorry @scaisEdge I didn't want to mean that... I can change type of course, and it works, so that's great! But the thing is that I want to have headings, a paragraph of text and maybe some images inside the infowindows, but If I have to put all that on the type, it won't be very practical. Ideally, using feature.message would be the perfect method, but can't make it work...

Comment: i have update the asnwer with a proper message property and a related  content  ... be sure you have a   proper comma   on theend of each  properties but not on at the last

Comment: @scaisEdge Yessss! :-) i was missing that coma.. Thanks a lot!